# I want the vertical lines to be there just to the far right and left side, but this is not happening?

Tags: tables, rules

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{xcolor}  %% THIS ONE IS USED FOR THE COLOUR MIX E.G. BlUE + BLACK
\definecolor{payne\'sgrey}{rgb}{0.25, 0.25, 0.28} %% OR define color == full list == http://latexcolor.com/
    \definecolor{sapphire}{rgb}{0.03, 0.15, 0.4}
        \definecolor{platinum}{rgb}{0.9, 0.89, 0.89}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}


\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}

\headheight 20.5pt       %% put this outside This blue rectangle the font be in the top
\headsep 10pt                %% put this outside

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{arydshln}


\begin{document}

\begin{changemargin}{0cm}{0cm} 
\crule[sapphire!50!sapphire!100]{25cm}{0.11cm} \\                                                                           %% TOP RECTANGLE
\end{changemargin}

\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
  \color{payne\'sgrey}                                                                                                                      %% SPACE BETWEEN TOP RECTANGLE & COMPANY NAME

\begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm}                                                                                                      
\Huge
\textbf{Company name}                                                                                                                    %% COMPANY NAME 
\smallskip
\end{changemargin}

\begin{changemargin}{2.1cm}{2.1cm}
\normalsize
\textbf  {Week X, xx-xx-201x – xx-xx-201x}\\
\smallskip
 \crule[sapphire!50!sapphire!100]{6cm}{0.11cm}                                                                               %% WEEK+RECTANGLE
 \end{changemargin}


\begin{picture}(10,20)
\put(40,00){\includegraphics[width=50mm]{box.png}}                                                              %% OVERVIEW
\put(50,10)  {1. OVERVIEW}
\end{picture}

\bigskip
\bigskip

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering % Centers the table on the page, comment out to left-justify



\begin{tabular}{l c | c | c l c l} 

% The final bracket specifies the number of columns in the table along with left and right borders which are specified using vertical bars (|); each column can be left, right or center-justified using l, r or c. To specify a precise width, use p{width}, e.g. p{5cm}

\toprule % Top horizontal line



\textbf{System STAT}     & Weekly (Qty.) & Weekly Growth \%  & Total (Qty.) \\ % Column names row
\bottomrule % In-table horizontal line \\
produced systems  \\ 
\midrule
active systems& x & x & x  \\ 
\midrule
registered systems & x & x & x  \\ %
\midrule
deactivated systems & x+y & x+y & x+y \\ 
\small
\hspace{0.3cm} no. of deactivated systems  & y & y & y \\ 
\small
\hspace{0.3cm} no. of previously active systems  & x & x & x \\ 
\textbf{Organization STAT} \\
\hdashline
\# organization & x & x & x \\ 
\midrule % In-table horizontal line
\textbf{User STAT} \\ 
\midrule

\# users & x & x & x \\ 
\midrule % In-table horizontal line
\midrule % In-table horizontal line
\textbf{Other STAT} \\
\small
\# avg. days from production to a system becomes active & x & x & x \\
\small
\% of active systems out of potential active systems \\ 
\footnotesize
(\#systems that should be active based on avg. time) \\ 
\small
\# avg. days from a system becomes active to registration & x & x & x  \\ % Summary/total row
\bottomrule % Bottom horizontal line
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{sysmon.png}};
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If you want  vertical lines (not recommended with booktabs) at specific places, mention it in the code.

Comment: It's my first day in latex, could you show one line example how i can do that?

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ |  c  |  c | c  |  c  |  } ` .... vertical lines in table are defined by `|`.

Comment: Yea I know, that's what I did as well, but in the picture you can see the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

The normal use of `booktabs` is not compatible with vertical lines, as these cannot intersect the horizontal lines of booktabs. See how ugly the internal vertical lines  look, in the following code. For the outer lines a work-around consists in using `\fbox` with convenient parameters :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{xcolor} %% THIS ONE IS USED FOR THE COLOUR MIX E.G. BlUE + BLACK
\definecolor{payne\'sgrey}{rgb}{0.25, 0.25, 0.28} %% OR define color == full list == http://latexcolor.com/
    \definecolor{sapphire}{rgb}{0.03, 0.15, 0.4}
        \definecolor{platinum}{rgb}{0.9, 0.89, 0.89}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}


\usepackage{eso-pic, graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0cm, headheight=20.5pt, headsep=10pt]{geometry}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{changemargin}{0cm}{0cm}
\crule[sapphire!50!sapphire!100]{25cm}{0.11cm} \\ %% TOP RECTANGLE
\end{changemargin}

\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
  \color{payne\'sgrey} %% SPACE BETWEEN TOP RECTANGLE & COMPANY NAME

\begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm}
\Huge
\textbf{Company name} %% COMPANY NAME
\smallskip
\end{changemargin}

\begin{changemargin}{2.1cm}{2.1cm}
\normalsize
\textbf {Week X, xx-xx-201x – xx-xx-201x}\\
\smallskip
 \crule[sapphire!50!sapphire!100]{6cm}{0.11cm} %% WEEK+RECTANGLE
 \end{changemargin}

\begin{picture}(10,20)
%\put(40,00){\includegraphics[width=50mm]{box.png}} %% OVERVIEW
\put(50,10) {1. OVERVIEW}
\end{picture}

\bigskip
\bigskip

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering % Centers the table on the page, comment out to left-justify
\setlength\fboxsep{-\heavyrulewidth}
\setlength\fboxrule{\heavyrulewidth}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{l c | c | c l c l}

% The final bracket specifies the number of columns in the table along with left and right borders which are specified using vertical bars (|); each column can be left, right or center-justified using l, r or c. To specify a precise width, use p{width}, e.g. p{5cm}

\toprule % Top horizontal line

\textbf{System STAT} & Weekly (Qty.) & Weekly Growth \% & Total (Qty.) \\ % Column names row
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth] % In-table horizontal line \\
produced systems \\
\midrule
active systems& x & x & x \\
\midrule
registered systems & x & x & x \\ %
\midrule
deactivated systems & x+y & x+y & x+y \\
\small
\hspace{0.3cm} no. of deactivated systems & y & y & y \\
\small
\hspace{0.3cm} no. of previously active systems & x & x & x \\
\textbf{Organization STAT} \\
\addlinespace[\aboverulesep]
\hdashline
\addlinespace[\belowrulesep]
\# organization & x & x & x \\
\midrule % In-table horizontal line
\textbf{User STAT} \\
\midrule

\# users & x & x & x \\
\midrule % In-table horizontal line
\midrule % In-table horizontal line
\textbf{Other STAT} \\
\small
\# avg. days from production to a system becomes active & x & x & x \\
\small
\% of active systems out of potential active systems \\
\footnotesize
(\#systems that should be active based on avg. time) \\
\small
\# avg. days from a system becomes active to registration & x & x & x \\ % Summary/total row
\bottomrule % Bottom horizontal line
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
%
%\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{sysmon.png}};%
%\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. But really, you can't use those vertical rules…

Comment: @Hussam if you want the vertical rules only on the border, just write `l c c c l c l` instead of `l c | c | c l c l`. By the way, why do you have defined 7 columns if your table has only 4? `l c c c` is enough!